# Is specific data point significantly different than simulated distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, z-score

I have performed a simulation 1000 times that has given me a distribution that looks like so:
[image]

I would now like to determine if a specific value (x = 140) is significantly different than the simulated distribution (mean = 103.9630, std = 9.6429). I would assume that the p-value for the specific value (x = 140) would be <0.01 because it falls above the distribution. However, I want to make sure I am thinking about this correctly. Is there a specific significance test I should be using?

Comment: You have an informal P-value of 0.001, as I read it. But that hinges entirely on one simulation sample. I am not sure what else you can do unless you fit a brand-name distribution to your data and try to estimate where the value would lie in that distribution.

Comment: @NickCox What if I was able to fit a normal distribution to my data?

Comment: I have fit the normal distribution to my data. The mean and std did not change

Comment: If the reported mean and SD do not change, that's because you fitted the normal in the usual way, by using the mean and SD of the data. That's not a finding, it's just a report on what you did. You can in any case plug your observed value into a normal cumulative distribution function, with other arguments the mean and the SD. But a normal distribution is at best an approximation unless you have independent grounds (e.g. physical arguments) for its applicability. From a graph, a normal distribution fit is not a lousy approximation, but one would need the data to assess quite how good it is.